# SQL issue when inputting an event on Joomla

Tags: sql

I run a gaming league on Joomla, I have set up the league via JoomSport, every time I input an event field I get this error:

> 0 - SQL=SELECT s.s_id as id, CONCAT(t.name,' ',s.s_name) as name,t.t_type,t.t_single FROM jos_bl_tournament as t, jos_bl_seasons as s WHERE s.s_id = 5 AND s.t_id = t.id

I have no idea how to solve it could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: @Nix That is all I get.

Comment: Is there more to it ?

Comment: @Nix No, Its really irritating me. I'm having so many issues with the database that is already supposed to be set up and working fine after spending £120 on it. Their own support forums are supported by no one.

Comment: I took a stab below, but i need you to post the columns for tournament and seasons.

Comment: @Nix Any idea where I can find the columns, as you already probably know I don't really know what the hell I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Complete shot in the dark.  Remove the as in the from statement:

`jos_bl_tournament as  t,` to -> `jos_bl_tournament t,`

```
SELECT 
   s.s_id as id, 
   CONCAT(t.name,' ',s.s_name) as name,
   t.t_type,
   t.t_single 
FROM 
  jos_bl_tournament  t, 
  jos_bl_seasons  s 
WHERE 
  s.s_id = 5 AND 
  s.t_id = t.id
```